# Enter Azure SQL Connection String in App Settings w/ PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-web-apps, azure-sql, connection-strings, azure-powershell

I've deployed an **Azure Web App and Azure SQL Database using PowerShell**. At the moment I have the following code with a dummy value that sets a **sql connection string** for my web app:

```
$connectionStrings = @{

"sqlConnection"= @{
    "value"="placeholder";
    "type"="3"

}
}
```

I would like to be able to enter a proper sql connection string for my azure sql database, like the following:
**Server=tcp:example.database.useastcloudapi.net;Database=ExampleDB;User Id=Admin;Password=Something123!;**

The issue im having is **entering/referencing the variables I've created containing the sql user account, password and server FQDN into the connection string value above**. Ideally, I'd like to do something like the following (I know that its incorrect but I want to reference the variables im using):

```
$connectionStrings = @{

"sqlConnection"= @{
    "value"="Server=tcp:"[$sqlServer];"Database="[$sqlDatabase];"User Id="[$sqlUser];
    "type"="3"

}
}
```

I don't have much experience with powershell and im not a developer so I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: [About Quoting Rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules). `"value"="Server=tcp:$sqlServer;Database=$sqlDatabase;User Id=$sqlUser;Password=$Password;"` could work…

Comment: That worked for me but now my issue is the $sqlServer variable only returns the sql server name and not the full server name - servername.database.region.net. I used Get-AzSqlDatabaseSecureConnectionPolicy to get the full server name (ProxyDnsName) value but when I reference this new variable in the conn string it also adds 'ProxyDnsName' along with the server name. Is there a way to remove ProxyDnsName from being entered in the conn string?